# How to pin an announcement on google classroom

Tags: google-classroom

In 2020 aprox Google introduced the option to pin an announcement at the top of the list (in the main page of the classroom), manually is an option inside the colon menu after you create an announcement.
I 'd need to use this option in a script, because I need to pin a document with rules in every classroom I have, but I can't find any reference in Classrooms API.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible programmatically at this time as there is no reference in the API to be able to do so with either announcements or course work materials, as you mentioned. I had looked to try to accomplish the same thing and came to the conclusion it's not yet supported. You could post this as a feature request in the Classroom issue tracker, I'm surprised I don't already see it there: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191645%20status:open

One alternate solution to make course work added via script easier to access as it gets pushed down the classroom feed is to make it posted to it's own topic:
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics

Comment: Tank you David Ferraro for your answer, I'll take a look to your alternate solution.